# TestDriven.net, right click, run test, doesn't re-build

Tags: c#, testdriven.net

I am using testDriven.net and when I right-click and run tests, it appears to build, then runs the test. Only it doesn't really do the build. I keep making changes and the test still fails:) I have to do a VS Build, then run the testDriven.net to get changes to take effect.

This clears up for a while if I delete the solution's .SUO file.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You already provided the workaround in your answer, which is to build first, then run your tests.

Is your version current?

**Release Notes - TestDriven.NET: 2.14**
*1390: Honour the solution 'Configuration Manager' project 'Build' settings*
When running all tests in a solution, only projects with 'Build' checked in the 'Configuration Manager' will be built and executed.

**Release Notes - TestDriven.NET: 2.12**
*1199: Improve support for "Smart Build"*
This version should correctly determine when a build is required before a test run. The previous version might incorrectly skip the build if only a non-source project item had changed.

Comment: I am behind a couple of versions so I will update that, but I've been using TestDriven for 2 to 3 years. It's worked well and doing the necessary build without having also do a VS build.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your only change is to a configuration file (or some other resource that's copied to the output directory conditionally, not a code file) then Visual Studio might skip the compile step. A clean/rebuild will fix this.

To diagnose this kind of problem, try turning up the verbosity of the MSBuild output in the Visual Studio environment. Choose Tools | Options, Projects and Solutions root item, then the Build and Run page. The default for the MSBuild project build verbosity is "Minimal" which is terse but sometimes not enough.